# During cppunit make install error for task install-m4DATA appeared

Tags: windows, makefile, mingw, cppunit

I've been building freedesktop cppunit with mingw

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/cppunit/

I've made some fixes to source files and makefiles and been able to
successfully execute commmands:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure 
make
```

without any errors.

There was a need to set

```
 m4_DATA = m4
```

instead of value "cppunit.m4" in Makefile.am(there was no such dir in build and it looks like such dir is "m4" dir).

After successful make execution doing

```
make --debug install
```

failed with error:

```
File install-m4DATA not found
```

from Makefile.am:

```
m4dir = $(datadir)/aclocal //what is datadir btw?
```

automake generated Makefile task:

```
install-m4DATA: $(m4_DATA)
@$(NORMAL_INSTALL) // fails at this line
test -z "$(m4dir)" || $(MKDIR_P) "$(DESTDIR)$(m4dir)"
@list='$(m4_DATA)'; test -n "$(m4dir)" || list=; \
for p in $$list; do \
  if test -f "$$p"; then d=; else d="$(srcdir)/"; fi; \
  echo "$$d$$p"; \
done | $(am__base_list) | \
while read files; do \
  echo " $(INSTALL_DATA) $$files '$(DESTDIR)$(m4dir)'"; \
  $(INSTALL_DATA) $$files "$(DESTDIR)$(m4dir)" || exit $$?; \
done
```

before that task NORMAL_INSTALL is set to:

```
NORMAL_INSTALL = :
```

How to fix "make install" execution.

Will it work if i have only mingw envieronment on my PC?

Version is 1.13.2 fresh from git repo.

I also post lines from "make --debug install" output

```
   File 'install-m4DATA' does not exist.
  Must remake target 'install-m4DATA'.
test -z "/usr/local/share/aclocal" || /usr/bin/mkdir -p     "/usr/local/share/aclocal"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./m4 '/usr/local/share/aclocal'
Makefile:432: recipe for target 'install-m4DATA' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory 'c:/Users/user/projects/cppunit'
Makefile:799: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory 'c:/Users/user/projects/cppunit'
Makefile:479: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
```

It also prints that that script omits directory at line

```
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./m4 '/usr/local/share/aclocal'
```

Possibly here must go files from directory but not directory itself.

How to fix it to do that(i'm not familiar with Makefiles and bash)?

Comment: I don't see any reason for MinGW not to be able to build that. Could you post the full Makefile ?

Comment: I don't know how to post the whole file, how to format it. I cannot make four spaces at each line of big file. I've also added some information to question

Comment: If this is still a problem can you open a bug report? This might be a makefile issue that I need to look at.

Comment: I decided to use google test framework because of that error, so it is kind of not an issue for me anymore. One question: are you able to build cppunit in windows?